# GraphQL not making request to WP API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, next.js, wp-api

Thanks in advance!

I'm pulling data from a WP Rest API and when spin up the wordpress site on my local machine with the address http://localhost:8000 and got to the graphqli playground on http://localhost:3000/api/graphql and i enter a query i get the expected results and i can consume the data happily in react but once i change the WP rest API address to http://example.com/cms i get back an error. The only thing that changes is the URL so i'm guessing it has to do with CORS.

Inspecting the browser window there is no CORS errors so i can rule out CORS being an issue. The strange thing is that when i make the api call via postman i get the response i expect, when i type in the endpoint in a browser i get the results i expect when i use the endpoint to resolve the query request i get an error, so i started to look at the headers as thats the only thing i can see that changes between a postman request and a normal browser request. for the local wp installation @ localhost:8000 looking at the logs i can see the request being made from postman and the browser and axios(used in the query resolver) on the flipside the wp installation thats live on the web the logs show the request from postman and from the browser to the api endpoint but not from the graphql resolver. how do i fix this issue with the resolver not making the request?

this is my resolver for the query

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        pages: (_parent, _args, _context) => {
            return axios.get(`${wpURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/pages`)
            .then(res => res.data)
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log("Response Status:", error.response.status);
                        console.log("Response Headers:", error.response.headers);
                        console.log("Response Data:", error.response.data);
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

graphqlserver:

```
import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server-micro'
import Cors from 'micro-cors'
import {schema} from './schema'

const cors = Cors()
const server = new ApolloServer({schema})
const handler = server.createHandler({path: '/api/graphql'})

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    }
}

export default cors(handler)
```

terminal:

```
> next dev

ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /api/graphql
wait  - compiling...
event - build page: /api/graphql
event - compiled successfully
```

page: [image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are the exact errors that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: on the browsers console no errors, the api call works via all other methods (ie postman, axios). So im thinking it has to do something with the `headers` being sent i added `credentials: include` reloaded but still the same error of graphql

Comment: If the browser console shows no errors, then you can at least safely rule out CORS

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out it looks like if the endpoint graphql is fetching data from is not secured via SSL it wont even bother asking for data